How to read gguf format file and print content in python such as in NLP meta''codellama-7b-instruct.Q4_K_S.gguf''
How to read gguf format file in python and print content in python such as in NLP  meta''codellama-7b-instruct.Q4_K_S.gguf''
I tried using Python's open() function to read the gguf format file, expecting to retrieve its content and print it to the console or store it in a variable. However, I encountered errors due to the unsupported file format, preventing me from accessing the content as intended.
